# How to view pictures using JFilechooser and Jlabel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel, jfilechooser

Hi guys I want to ask how can I view Images using Jlabel and attach that image using Jfilechooser?

what code do I use so that when I attached a image it will automatically shown in the Jlabel?

Thanks in advance

Here is my JFileChooser code:

```
JFileChooser image=new JFileChooser();
    image.showOpenDialog(null);
    File f=image.getSelectedFile();
    filename=f.getAbsolutePath();
    txtFilename.setText(filename);

    try{



        File images=new File(filename);
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(images);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
        for(int readNum;(readNum=fis.read(buf))!=-1;){

            bos.write(buf,0,readNum);

        }
        person_image=bos.toByteArray();

    }
    catch(IOException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Image image = null;
    try {
      JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();
      fc.showOpenDialog(null);
      File f=fc.getSelectedFile();

        image = ImageIO.read(f);      

    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    // Use a label to display the image
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: why do i need another jframe?

Comment: It's just an example,you have to adapt it to your application.So,yes you don't need another jframe, just use yours.hope it helps

Comment: iwant tosave that image i attached to my database

Comment: that's another question; here you wanted just to view it, so you should perhaps mark my answer as the correct one, then ask the other question and may be I will help :)